# How do I get to change the View that is going to be displayed by ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

`ViewPager.getChildAt(int position).findViewById(int id)` does not return the correct View in `SimpleOnPageChangeListener.onPageSelected()`. And so I thought I'm maybe "holding it wrong".

In my activity I'm trying to do something with the views (remove/change text in EditTexts)

```
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            EditText edit = (EditText) pager
                .getChildAt(position)
                .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        }
    });
```

Sometimes I get "old" views (from 1 or 2 pages before). Sometimes I get nothing. I don't know if this is supposed to not work or it's actually a bug. Anyone have any ideas? Or are there workarounds to change views when they're being displayed in a ViewPager? (Or is this just bad practice?)

**Note**: `getFocusedChild()` always returns the view where you came from.

Comment: What do you want exactly? Manually selecting a page?

Comment: No, I'd like to do something* after the page was created (not necessarily viewed). *: For example I want to change the content of an EditText dynamically.